# How do I disable Lion's Resume feature?

Tags: macos, preferences, resume

Some of my software will be loaded at login, but I don't want it to be loaded as-it-was when I closed it. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 7):

To turn off Lion's Resume feature just go to **System Preferences > General** and uncheck *"Restore Windows when quitting and re-opening apps"*.

Once rebooted, won't do it again.

Answer (score 2):

When you confirm the re-start or turn-off of your mac, there's a checkbox that determines how apps will be loaded back, un-check it and it will not load the open software to the state you've closed your mac with.

Comment: The answer here.

Answer (score 2):

When you shut down your Mac, you can select "reopen current applications", try to deselect that option. If that is not what you want (your English is not that good), check http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/#appstartup